# How to Get rows that are added 'x' minutes before in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff

I want to get all rows that have being added `'x' minutes` before.

```
SELECT [PromoCodeID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[DiscountAmount]
      ,[AddedBy]
      ,[AddedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
 FROM [tbl_PromoCodesNewCustomer]
 Where....
```

**Eg:** *Records added 30min before from todays date time*

**NOTE: Record Added date is added in the field `'AddedDate'` which has `DATETIME` datatype.**

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I'd advise you to populate the addedDate field with the UTC date and time, otherwise you could have problems with data managed among different servers \ time zones or on time change days.

So, if we consider this, the where clause will be:

WHERE DATEDIFF(mi,addedDate,GETUTCDATE)<30

Comment: You're right! I guess I was thinking about something else. Then you have to make use of the datediff function, setting the interval to minutes, and checking that it's result stays below 'x'...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT [PromoCodeID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[DiscountAmount]
      ,[AddedBy]
      ,[AddedDate] AS added
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
FROM [tbl_PromoCodesNewCustomer]
WHERE DATEADD(minute,x,added) > GETDATE()
```

Where "x" in DATEADD is the number of minutes you want.

Comment: please read the question title..its minute :) Do u mean X=AddedDate?

Comment: Just change the part where it says "second" to "minute" in the DATEADD method. That way X is now in minutes.

Comment: i have "AddedDate"=2014-10-22 15:15:39.510 and x=25 but still it wont show...where as GETDATE()=2014-10-22 18:36:39.873 :(

Comment: GETDATE() returns the current time on the server. So when you ran the query there the time was 18:36 / 6:36 PM. The time portion in your "AddedDate" is 15:15 / 3:15 PM. Therefore it was added more than 25 minutes ago, and therefore is not displayed in the query.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest a light variation on FirstHorizon answer:

```
SELECT [PromoCodeID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[DiscountAmount]
      ,[AddedBy]
      ,[AddedDate] AS added
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
FROM [tbl_PromoCodesNewCustomer]
WHERE AddedDate < DATEADD(minute * -1,x,getdate())
```

the change may look minor but depending on the number of involved rows, indexes and some other factor evaluated by the query optimizer this query may perform way better because there is no calc to make on the data.

[here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/) is an article that explain the reason (look at the second paragraph, 'Using Functions in Comparisons within the ON or WHERE Clause').